# Голосов отдано "за" период

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Везде "за", кроме статистики "за" день.

В оригинале там всё в одном стиле.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может приведём к одному формату?

Comment: Я бы, если честно, убрал бы "за" вовсе тут.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ остальное в именительном падеже?

Comment: ну, да. Можно еще в уэб-архиве глянуть старые варианты.

Comment: В английском варианте проще, так как там продолжение однородности и повторять "by" не нужно, достаточно один раз. По такой логике в русском варианте можно последний раз написать "за" там где "за месяц", а дальше убрать; или перенести "за" в шапку "Голосов отдано за" и тогда заменить "по типу" на просто "тип", а "за" соответственно везде убрать.